# Integration by parts does not work for this complex integral. Why?

Tags: integration, solution-verification, complex-numbers, complex-integration, constants

There is a longer integral for which integration by parts $\displaystyle\int udv=uv-\int vdu$ was attempted as it came across in research:

$$\frac i{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\underbrace{\ln\left(1+\frac{e^{-i t}+1}a\ln\left(1-\frac1be^{\frac{e^{it}+1}a}\right)\right)}_ud\bigg[\underbrace{\ln\left(e^\frac{e^{it}+1}c-b\right)}_v\bigg] \tag{0}$$

as it has the below problem, but here is a simpler one to better get the point across

$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(e^{it}+a)d\left[\ln\left(e^{e^{it}}-2\right)\right] \tag{1}$$

Integrating (1) by parts should give:

$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(e^{it}+a)d\left[\ln\left(e^{e^{it}}-2\right)\right] = \underbrace{\left[\ln(e^{it}+a)\ln\left(e^{e^{it}}-2\right)\middle]\right|_0^{2\pi}}_\text{should equal zero when plugging in directly}-\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(e^{e^{it}}-2\right) d\left[\ln(e^{it}+a)\right] \tag{2}$$

Directly substituting, we should get $\left[\ln(e^{it}+a)\ln\left(e^{e^{it}}-2\right)\middle]\right|_0^{2\pi} =0$. [Checking numerically](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B1%2F%282+%CF%80%29NIntegrate%5Bln%28e%5E%28i+t%29%2B5%29+D%5Bln%28e%5E%28e%5E%28i+t%29%29-2%29%2Ct%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2%CF%80%7D%5D%2C-1%2F%282+%CF%80%29NIntegrate%5BD%5Bln%28e%5E%28i+t%29%2B5%29%2Ct%5D+ln%28e%5E%28e%5E%28i+t%29%29-2%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2%CF%80%7D%5D%7D) shows $(2)$ to be false. However, instead, we [numerically get](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B1%2F%282+%CF%80%29NIntegrate%5Bln%28e%5E%28i+t%29%2B5%29+D%5Bln%28e%5E%28e%5E%28i+t%29%29-2%29%2Ct%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2%CF%80%7D%5D%2Cln%285-1%29*i+-1%2F%282+%CF%80%29NIntegrate%5BD%5Bln%28e%5E%28i+t%29%2B5%29%2Ct%5D+ln%28e%5E%28e%5E%28i+t%29%29-2%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2%CF%80%7D%5D%7D) $\ln(a-1)i$ instead of $0$:

$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(e^{it}+a)d\left[\ln\left(e^{e^{it}}-2\right)\right]=\ln(a-1)i -\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(e^{e^{it}}-2\right) d\left[\ln(e^{it}+a)\right] \tag{3}$$

What is the correct way to find the extra $[uv]|_a^b$ term, like $\ln(a-1)i$ here?

Comment: Here (2) looks right. In which text book was (3) given ? What was that numerical calculation ?

Comment: BTW , (2) & (3) long & could be shortened with $I=\cdots$ in (1) & using that $I$ in (2) & (3)

Comment: The issue might be because $\ln$ is multivalued on $\mathbb{C}$? Which branch of $\ln$ you are choosing presumably affects this. Especially when $|a| < 1$, you would be looping around $0$, so the boundary term is definitely *not* $0$.

Comment: Even if $|a| > 1$, if the branch cut of $\ln$ intersects with the circle you’re integrating over, this is still an issue.

Comment: [[A]] I am not getting what the OP question is about ? [[B]] Who is claiming that (3) is wrong , while (2) is right ? [[C]] Which text book is claiming that (2) is wrong , while (3) is right ? [[D]] Details are missing making it unanswerable !

Comment: @Prem [[A]] The integration by parts $[uv]|_a^b$ term is incorrect when directly substituting, so the question asks how one would correctly evaluate it . [[B]] The question actually claims $(3)$ is right while $(2)$ is wrong. [[C]] It is not a textbook, but rather numerical verification and $(1)$ is a simpler integral than $(0)$ to get the point of the question across [[D]] The question has been edited for such readers, so please review it. Does this help?